# Setting up a toString() method for an array list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Sorry for what is probley a simple question but how would i go about setting up a toString() method for an array list?

is it as simple as

```
points = new ArrayList<Point>();
public String toString() {
return points.toString();}
```

which does not seem to be working for me, or would it be more complex since it is a array list? Because for some reason when i execute mine like this its only printing the first value or object.

P.S I'm trying to return all the values that i have already added to my list.

More in detail
constructer

```
public Cloud() {
    points = new ArrayList<Point>();
}
```

add point

```
public void addPoint(Point p) { // done
    if (points.contains(p)) {
        // if p is already in the list it does nothing
    } else {
        points.add(p); // if p was not in the list it adds it to the end
    }
}
```

toString

```
public String toString() {
    return points.toString();
}
```

main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cloud cloud = new Cloud();

    cloud.setDebug(false);
    System.out.println("cloud.debug OFF");

    System.out.println("initial cloud: " + cloud.toString());
    Point p1 = new Point(3.0, 1.0);
    cloud.addPoint(p1);

    Point p2 = new Point(2.0, 2.0);
    cloud.addPoint(p2);

    Point p3 = new Point(1.5, 1.5);
    cloud.addPoint(p3);

    Point p4 = new Point(3.0, 0.0);
    cloud.addPoint(p4);

    System.out.println("final cloud: " + cloud);
```

This is just printing final cloud: (3.0,1.0)     while it should be printing final cloud: [(3.0,1.0), (2.0,2.0), (1.5,1.5), (3.0,0.0)]

edit: Points class

```
public class Point {

private double x;
private double y;

public static final double EPSILON = 1e-5;
public static boolean debug = false;

public Point(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y; // Done sets the x,y private types to the x,y type provided
                // in the ()
}

public Point() {
    this(0.0, 0.0); // calls the point (double x,double) constructer with
                    // the given arguments
} // inturn setting x and y == 0.0

public double getX() {
    return x; // returns the private value of x when called in the main
                // method
} // so it can't be changed by the user

public double getY() {
    return y; // return the private value of y when called in the main
                // method so it can't be changed
} // by the user

public String toString() {
    return "(" + x + "," + y + ")"; // done by teacher sets the toString
                                    // method and implemetns it
}

public boolean equals(Point p) {
    if (Math.abs(this.getX()) - Math.abs(p.x) < EPSILON) {
        return true; // checks if x - p.x is less than epsilon which covers
                        // the round off
    }
    if (Math.abs(this.getY()) - Math.abs(p.y) < EPSILON) {
        return true; // checks if y-p.y is less than epsilon which covers
                        // the round off
    }
    return false; // both these methods test for equality using epsilon,
                    // becuae we are dealing with
} // doubles, so roundof can occur

public boolean equals(Object obj) { // this was given to us
    if (obj instanceof Point) {
        Point p = (Point) obj; // This method overrides the object equals
                                // method and the calls
        return equals(p); // the clas's equals(point) method
    }
    return false;
}

// TODO Implement Point.euclidDist
/**
 * 
 * @param p
 * @return Euclidean distance of this point to point p
 */
public double euclidDist(Point p) {
    double distance = 0;
    double firstvalue;
    double secondvalue;
    distance = Math.sqrt(((this.getX() - p.x) * (this.getX() - p.x)) // calculate
                                                                        // the
                                                                        // distance
            + ((this.getY() - p.y) * (this.getY() - p.y))); // between the
                                                            // two points
    // firstvalue= Math.pow(this.getX()-p.x, 2);
    // secondvalue= Math.pow(this.getY()-p.y, 2);
    // distance = Math.sqrt(firstvalue + secondvalue);

    return distance;
}

/**
 * @param args
 *            : no args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // test all methods

    if (debug)
        System.out.println("debug ON");
    else
        System.out.println("debug OFF");

    System.out.println("EPSILON: " + Point.EPSILON);

    Point origin = new Point();
    Point p1 = new Point(0.0, 4.0);
    Point p2 = new Point(3.0000001, 3.9999999);
    Point p3 = new Point(3.0, 4.0);

    Point p4 = new Point(0.0, 5.0);
    Point p5 = new Point(12.0, 0.0);

    System.out.println("origin: " + origin);
    System.out.println("p1: " + p1);
    System.out.println("p2: " + p2);
    System.out.println("p3: " + p3);
    System.out.println("p4: " + p4);
    System.out.println("p5: " + p5);

    if (p2.equals(p3))
        System.out.println(p2 + " equals " + p3);
    else
        System.out.println(p2 + " does not equal " + p3);

    System.out.println("Euclidean distance between " + origin + " and "
            + p1 + ": " + origin.euclidDist(p1));

    System.out.println("Euclidean distance between " + p1 + " and " + p3
            + ": " + p1.euclidDist(p3));

    System.out.println("Euclidean distance between " + p3 + " and "
            + origin + ": " + p3.euclidDist(origin));

    System.out.println("Euclidean distance between " + p4 + " and " + p5
            + ": " + p4.euclidDist(p5));

}
```

}

Comment: You need to over ride the `toString()` in `Point` class as well.

Comment: @NikhilTalreja: that's not the problem. Point already has a toString. The issue is with the data he's adding to the list.

Comment: Where is the code for `Point` class?

Comment: Just a tip, since you've made the mistake a second time, you shouldn't leave personal info in your code when you post it on the internet...

Answer (score 1):

You can only create `toString()` method overrides in classes of yours, not in other classes that you're not overriding. ArrayList already has a valid `toString()` method that is useful. You will just need to make sure that the items held by the List are from a class that also has a valid toString() method.

Note you state:

> which does not seem to be working for me... 
>   Because for some reason when i execute mine like this its only printing the first value or object.

This suggests that you don't have a toString() problem, but that you actually have another completely different problem with your program, that you're not adding objects to the list correctly. You need to do more debugging and show more pertinent code.

---

**Edit**
I'm guessing that your Point class's `contains(...)` method is erroneous, that it is returning `true` when it should be returning false. Please show us the Point class.

---

**Edit 3** (deleted edit 2)
Your equals is wrong:

This is OK:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) { // this was given to us
    if (obj instanceof Point) {
        Point p = (Point) obj; // This method overrides the object equals
                                // method and the calls
        return equals(p); // the clas's equals(point) method
    }
    return false;
}
```

But here, you return equals if either x's or y's closely match and that shouldn't be. You should only return true if ***BOTH*** closely match:

```
public boolean equals(Point p) {
    if (Math.abs(this.getX()) - Math.abs(p.x) < EPSILON) {
        return true; // checks if x - p.x is less than epsilon which covers
                        // the round off
    }
    if (Math.abs(this.getY()) - Math.abs(p.y) < EPSILON) {
        return true; // checks if y-p.y is less than epsilon which covers
                        // the round off
    }
    return false; // both these methods test for equality using epsilon,
                    // becuae we are dealing with
} // doubles, so roundof can occur
```

Also you're using `Math.abs(...)` incorrectly. It should go around the subtraction statement, not around each variable.

Comment: When i call my points/cloud in my main it is just printing the first value i added which seems weird to me

Comment: @user3777537: that has absolutely nothing to do with `toString()` and your toString is working correctly. Your problem really is why do you just have the first value in your list. Please improve your question.

Comment: I have updated it. Can you please have a look now as to why it is only printing my first value?

Comment: @user3777537: so you're not using `java.awt.Point`, instead you're using your own Point class.... and does it use **static** fields per chance? Show the Point class. And what of your `contains(...)` method -- **That** is where the problem could be!

Comment: Points is just my arraylist which would refer back to cloud right?.. I have a sperate Point class but should have nothing to do with my list.

Comment: @user3777537: cripes you're missing the point -- please re-read my edit to my answer. The Point class has **everything** to do with your problem. Please just show it.

Comment: @user3777537: than you. see edit. Your equals method is wrong messing up contains.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm just not sure what overload would be called in `ArrayList`... It's parameterized as `Point`, but generics are erased, so I don't know if the compiler would bind the `Object` overload or the `Point` overload

Comment: @user3777537: no I'm right. Your equals is wrong for another reason. You're short circuiting it if x1 == x2 it returns true regardless of the y's. Not good.

Comment: Yes i have fixed that problem but it only returns the first two values now not the last two i'll keep working but thank you for your help i would have never found that.

Comment: and just to clarify your saying as it should be how i changed it to in my quesiton.

Comment: @user3777537: you can find out if correct by running test code. The lesson to gain from your question is to not assume where your error lies, to do debugging before coming here so that you first isolate your error. You will save yourself and us a lot of time.

Comment: @user3777537: re-think your use of `Math.abs(...)` Going to bed now. Good luck!